# How do I convert an Array[String] to a Set[String]?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have an array of strings. What's the best way to turn it into an immutable set of strings?

I presume this is a single method call, but I can't find it in the scala docs.

I'm using scala 2.8.1.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This method called `toSet`, e.g.:

```
scala> val arr = Array("a", "b", "c")
arr: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(a, b, c)

scala> arr.toSet
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[java.lang.String] = Set(a, b, c)
```

In this case `toSet` method does not exist for the `Array`. But there is an implicit conversion to [ArrayOps](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps.html).

In such cases I can advise you to look in [Predef](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Predef$). Normally you should find some suitable implicit conversion there. `genericArrayOps` would be used in this case. `genericWrapArray` also can be used, but it has lower priority.

Answer (score 13):

```
scala> val a = Array("a", "b", "c")
a: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(a, b, c)

scala> Set(a: _*)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[java.lang.String] = Set(a, b, c)

// OR    

scala> a.toSet
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[java.lang.String] = Set(a, b, c)
```

Comment: One little comment... The only reason I'd prefer Set(a: _*) over .toSet is if I wanted a mutable set, e.g. `collection.mutable.Set(a: _*)`