# foreach() in scala returns a Seq. How to get to the item?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to add every element of a list to a MutableSet.

Thrift:

```
Obj {
  list<Tag> myList;
}

enum Tag {
  ...
}
```

Scala:

```
val uniqueTags = Set[Tag]()
// obj is of type Obj defined in the thrift above
obj.flatMap(_.myList).foreach(uniqueTags += _)
```

However the compiler says that I'm trying to add `Seq[Tag]` instead of `Tag`. How to get to the element represented by Seq?

Also I'm sure there is another way to initialize the Set with the list directly. I tried `obj.flatMap(_.myList).toSet()` and `Set[Tag](obj.flatMap(_.myList))`) but none worked.

Comment: would you mind what is type of `obj`?

Comment: obj is of type Obj (see the Thrift definiition)

Comment: can you post the type of `obj.flatMap(_.myList)` only?

Comment: `Set(obj.flatMap(_.myList).flatten:_*)` (just a guess)

Comment: @prayagupd Option[Seq[Tag]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**you don't need to iterate to find unique, [scala does that for you with `toSet`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5778677/432903)**

**Example using `toSet`:**

```
scala> case class Obj(myList: List[String])
defined class Obj

scala> val obj = Option(Obj(myList = List("metal", "rock", "prog", "pop", "pop")))
obj: Option[Obj] = Some(Obj(List(metal, rock, prog, pop, pop)))
```

Now, to get unique tags,

```
scala> val uniqueTags = obj.map(_.myList).getOrElse(List.empty[String]).toSet
uniqueTags: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(metal, rock, prog, pop)
```

**`foreach` are not recommended to mutate stuffs in fp world. The other approach would be to use [accumulator pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007747/functional-way-to-map-over-a-list-with-an-accumulator-in-scala) - `foldLeft`,**

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable.Set
import scala.collection.immutable.Set

scala> obj.map(_.myList).getOrElse(List.empty[String]).foldLeft(Set[String]()){ case (s, e) => s + e }
res15: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(metal, rock, prog, pop)
```

**The mutable approach is to use `forach` as you are doing, (not recommended)**

```
scala> val uniqueTags = scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]()
uniqueTags: scala.collection.mutable.Set[String] = HashSet()

scala> obj.map(_.myList).getOrElse(List.empty[String]).foreach { elem => uniqueTags += elem }

scala> uniqueTags
res13: scala.collection.mutable.Set[String] = HashSet(metal, rock, pop, prog)
```

Comment: @Thomas would you mind postind only the type of `obj.flatMap(_.myList)`, that will help the exact answer

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer but still not working (the type after compiling from thrift is Option[Seq[Tag]]) for obj.flatmap(_.myList)

Comment: Cool, you have to `obj.flatMap(_.myList).getOrElse(List.empty[Tag]).foreach(uniqueTags += _)`. See updated answer as well. So basically you are iterating on `Option`, not `Seq`, or `List`.

Answer (score 0):

I an not sure what is Obj. But in you case: `obj.flatMap(_.myList)` will give a list of Tag. I think the correct way is:

```
obj.flatMap(_.myList).foreach(uniqueTags += _)
```

I think you can use mutable in Scala. Its not a big deal. According to your obj, you may use different way to append the element into set

```
case class Obj(myList: List[String])
val obj = Obj(List("1", "2", "3"))

// first example when your obj is a single Obj
val uniqueTags = mutable.Set[String]()
// obj is of type Obj defined in the thrift above
obj.myList.foreach(uniqueTags += _)
printf(uniqueTags.toString()) // give you Set(1, 2, 3)

// second example when your obj is a list of Obj
val obj2 = List(obj, obj, obj)
val uniqueTags2 = mutable.Set[String]()
obj2.flatMap(_.myList).foreach(uniqueTags2 += _)
printf(uniqueTags2.toString()) // give you Set(1, 2, 3) also
```

Comment: the compiler still complains `_` is a Seq[Tag]